# InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

im very new to python, trying to create reusable code. when i try to call the class Login and function login_user in test_main.py by passing all the arguments that were used under Login class, im getting an error as InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string.

test_main.py file which runs on pytest.

Locators_test is the class of test_Locators.py file where i have all my xpaths

test_Locators.py

```
class Locators_test():

loginlink_xpath = "//a[@id='login-link']"
login_email = "xxxxx"
login_password = "xxxxx"
loginemail_id = "dnn_ctr1179_Login_txtEmail"
loginpassword_id = "dnn_ctr1179_Login_txtPassword"
clicklogin_id = "dnn_ctr1179_Login_btnLogin"
```

test_login.py

```
from Smoketest.locatorfile.test_Locators import Locators_test

class Login():

def __init__(self,driver):

    self.driver = driver

def login_user(self,driver):
    try:
        loginButton = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath))
        while loginButton.click() is True:
            break
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300);")

        EmailField = self.driver.find_element((By.ID, Locators_test.loginemail_id))
        EmailField.send_keys(Locators_test.login_email)

        PasswordField = self.driver.find_element((By.ID, Locators_test.loginpassword_id))
        PasswordField.send_keys(Locators_test.login_password)

        ClickLogin = self.driver.find_element((By.ID, Locators_test.clicklogin_id))
        while ClickLogin.click() is True:
            break

        time.sleep(5)

        userName = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.username_xpath))
        print("Logged in as", userName.text)



    except StaleElementReferenceException or ElementClickInterceptedException or TimeoutException as ex:
        print(ex.message)
```

test_main.py

```
    def test_setup():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= Locators_test.browser_path)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.get(homePage)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        yield
        print("test complete")


def test_login(test_setup):

    from Smoketest.pages.test_login import Login

    lo = Login(driver)
lo.login_user(((Locators_test.loginlink_xpath,Locators_test.loginemail_id,Locators_test.login_email,Locators_test.loginpassword_id,Locators_test.login_password,Locators_test.clicklogin_id,Locators_test.username_xpath)))
```

***indentations are all fine***

Comment: Which line is throwing the error message?

Comment: Could you please add the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @svetlannnka `..\pages\test_login.py:15: in login_user
    loginButton = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath))
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:978: in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)`

Comment: `self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x0345FBF0>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"invalid argument: \'using\' must be a string...\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77AE662D+237]\\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77AE65FD+189]\\n"}}'}`

Comment: @supputuri error occurs in `loginButton = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath))`  `Locators_test.loginlink_xpath = "//a[@id='login-link']"` mentioned error messages in above comments

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I fixed it myself by removing the extra pair of parenthesis from the line

`loginButton = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath))`

Right way is

`loginButton = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath)`

ps: this applies to all the lines.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me,

```
locator = (By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath)
self.driver.find_element(*locator).click()
```

**Explanation:** In `*<arguments>`, all positional arguments other than the first one will be packed in a tuple, as they won't get Changed, the exact property will be reflected in the second step.