# Selenium element.text() is not considered as a string

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to get an element name with python selenium and print it later but it throws following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

Code line looks like this:

```
title = driver.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mt-3')).text()
```

HTML element looks like this:

```
<h1 class="mt-3">ElementTitle</h1>
```

I tried searcing for element by XPath but it seems not to be a reason for error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a web element text you should apply `.text` on it, not `.text()`
Also, there are unnecessary parenthesis here that should be removed.
So, instead of

```py
title = driver.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mt-3')).text()
```

it should be

```py
title = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'mt-3').text
```

Comment: Maybe also consider to remove the double paranthesis. As mentionend in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395570/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-using-must-be-a-string

Comment: @DevStarter101 you are right, thanks

Comment: Thanks! I needed to do both for it to work

Comment: I know, I just didn't pay attention to the redundant parenthesis at the first look.